# Overlap 2 paragraphs responsively

Tags: javascript, css

For a project I would like some paragraphs to transition from one text content to another. The method I would like to use is to have two paragraphs in my HTML, but only one is visible at a time.

I have the transition working fine, but I can't find a way to overlap the two paragraphs in a responsive way. Anybody know how to make this work?

Here's what I have so far (all I'm missing is the responsive paragraph overlap):

```js
var a = document.getElementById("switch");
a.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show1");
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show2");
  return false;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.text1,
.text2 {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.show1 > .text1,
.show2 > .text2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="show1">
  <p class="text1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel ipsum dolor. Nulla vitae laoreet turpis.
  </p>
  <p class="text2">
    Proin feugiat ex est, a sollicitudin felis tincidunt at. Fusce quis quam ut nisl feugiat fermentum blandit non metus.
  </p>
</div>
<a id="switch" href="#">Switch paragraph</a>
```

If this is just a bad way to do it then please let me know.

The reason I want this to be responsive and not rely on absolute positioning or margins of -104px is because I would like to use this method on other things than paragraphs (buttons, navbars, etc.) as well, not just because I want it to look good on a smaller screen (even though I do want it to look good on a smaller screen!) :)

Comment: Positioning or margins are the only ideal "overlay" methods. You might be better swapping out the content than using overlays.

Comment: So basically you want the red-bordered container to gently change height as the inner contents x-fade?

Comment: @Paulie_D in my project I wouldn't always have paragraphs with similar sizes, and in that case I wouldn't want the switch to change the overall layout of my page. Although I do agree that changing the content would be simpler.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan actually I would like the red-bordered container to never change size, being from the start the appropriate size for the biggest of the two paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can do that would fit your description. We're lacking too many constrains here to display the overlay paragraph correctly in all cases...

```js
var a = document.getElementById("switch");
a.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show1");
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show2");
  return false;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.text1,
.text2 {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.show1 > .text1,
.show2 > .text2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.show1 > .text2,
.show2 > .text1{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="show1">
  <p class="text1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel ipsum dolor. Nulla vitae laoreet turpis.
  </p>
  <p class="text2">
    Proin feugiat ex est, a sollicitudin felis tincidunt at. Fusce quis quam ut nisl feugiat fermentum blandit non metus.
  </p>
</div>
<a id="switch" href="#">Switch paragraph</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though paragraphs hide with `opacity: 0` their size is still calculated by your browser. You need to make them both overlap each other.
To do so **you need to combine** `display: none/block` with the `opacity`.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xctLmLae/1/

Answer (score -1):

How about switching `display` instead of `opacity`:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("switch");
a.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show1");
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("show2");
  return false;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.text1,
.text2 {
  transition: display 1s ease;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.show1 > .text1,
.show2 > .text2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="show1">
  <p class="text1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel ipsum dolor. Nulla vitae laoreet turpis.
  </p>
  <p class="text2">
    Proin feugiat ex est, a sollicitudin felis tincidunt at. Fusce quis quam ut nisl feugiat fermentum blandit non metus.
  </p>
</div>
<a id="switch" href="#">Switch paragraph</a>
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the fade in/out transition, even though it makes things trickier.